# D3, how to ungroup x-axis similar values

Tags: d3.js, axis-labels

I am new to d3.  I am trying to display all values on the x-axis, however the code is grouping similar values.  How can I ungroup so that all values show.  Even duplicates.  Here is my code:

```
//JSON DATA
var data = [
  {
    "due": 89.99, 
    "datestr": "2012-12-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 89.99
  }, 
  {
    "due": 89.99, 
    "datestr": "2013-01-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 101.25
  }, 
  {
    "due": 109.99, 
    "datestr": "2013-02-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 143.69
  }

];

//Set Axis
var due = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width])
                  .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.due; }));
```

Comment: See full code here https://jsfiddle.net/keturp/df00fyuu/

Comment: The D3 scales will always map duplicates to the same value. You could use the index of the values for the scale/axis instead of the actual value.

Comment: what is the correct way to do that?  Here is what I tried:
`var due = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]).domain([0, d[i].due]);`

Comment: You would use just the index, i.e. just `i`.

Comment: I'm not following.  I tried using i, and that did not work.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried please?

Comment: I tried a few variations.  Here is one:
`var due = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]).domain(function(d, i) { return i; });`

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is post the Object Value 'due' as the x-axis,  without any grouping.

Comment: Well your domain would be `[0, data.length - 1]` then.

Comment: I think that's close.  That will show the data length.  However I need specifically the 'due' information to be shown.  you can see the updated code,, http://jsfiddle.net/keturp/df00fyuu/

Comment: You can use the [`.tickFormat()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) to do this -- index into `data` with the index given.

Comment: That worked! but it doesn't split across the chart.   do you know how I can accomplish that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "split across the chart".